# Jade if else shorthand to select checkbox

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

```
select.className(((#{obj.active} == 1) ? selected : disabled))
```

I don't know why this return me an error of `Unexpected token =`, for me the logic is fine. I must done something wrong somewhere.

Comment: let try : select(class=(#{obj.active} == 1) ? "selected" : "disabled")

Comment: I can see an extra closing bracket ) at the end, try removing that..

Comment: @ManojSalvi that's not extra bracket, tried to remove it it doesnt work

Comment: @trquoccuong Unexpected token ILLEGAL and where is my ClassName?

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here:

1. You are trying to use [interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html) inside an expression, which both isn't needed and doesn't work, and
2. The outputs of your ternary operator aren't quoted, which Jade/Pug will interpret as variables and not strings.

Note that this error message is caused by the first problem.

Here is the correct statement to use here:

```
select.className( obj.active == 1 ? 'selected' : 'disabled' )
```

If your `obj.active` variable is either 1 or 0 (or undefined) then consider simplifying it as the "truthiness" of a ternary operator will reject both 0 and undefined and resolve the second value:

```
select.className( obj.active ? 'selected' : 'disabled' )
```